# Flashget download stopped near ending

Tags: download, download-manager

I am downloading stellarium using Flashget. I have downloaded 75.61 Mb out of 75.71 Mb but now flashget is stuck and I can't do anything. I have tried to pause and resume the download many times, but it is not working. So how to continue the download?

[image: Flashget stuck at 99%]